# Does 'for' always comes after search?

Tags: prepositions

Is it a rule that 'for' should follow after word 'search'?

Does any form of search should be followed by for?
For example,
searched for
searching for

Comment: A search *on* Google might help answer this.  You might get a few friends to help conduct this search *but* I would imagine that it wouldn't be too long before the search *was* called off.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/search

Comment: @Jim, that comment is really unhelpful. I am sure that the OP is asking about ways to express the target of the search rather than literally "the following word". To which the answer is "yes, the target of the search is always indicated by the word 'for'".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Search' can be used both as a verb and a noun.

When used as a noun it can be followed by 'for'. e.g 'They conducted a search for the body', but need not be as in 'The police have done a thorough search of the premises.'

Used as a verb it sometimes takes 'for'. e.g. 'I am searching for my socks', but not always e.g. We searched the woods thoroughly but there was no sign of the missing dog'.

Comment: When conducting a search for something, *search* is generally followed by *for*.

Comment: @Andrew Leach I can think of multiple examples where you wouldn't use 'for'. e.g. 'We searched high and low but could find nothing' or 'I searched the room from top to bottom, and eventually I found what I needed'.

Comment: But you said "never" for a noun.

Comment: @Andrew Leach Right, I see what you mean. Apologies. I will edit my answer.

Comment: WS2, I think this answer is unhelpful. _For_ is always used (AFAICS) to express the target of the search. The other words you give express different properties of the search.

Comment: @Colin Fine There are many Google hits for [they searched after the](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/search+after) etc.

Comment: @Colin Fine But the question asked was whether 'for' should always follow the word 'search'. The answer is categorically 'no'! And I have supplied perfectly proper examples. Until you raised it no one said anything about 'target of the search and other properties of the search'.

Comment: @Colin Fine Used as a verb 'search' is both transitive and intransitive. The item being sought is never the direct object, hence any reference to that requires the preposition'for'. The only way of making 'my socks' in the example a direct object would be to say 'I am seeking my socks'. In other words we  search a location, we seek an object/body.

Comment: There's a whole class of verbs (Levin class 35.2, "_search_ verbs"), including _advertise check comb dive drag dredge excavate patrol plumb probe prospect prowl quarry rake rifle scavenge scour scout search shop sift trawl troll watch_. These are implicated in Levin class 2.11, _"Search" Alternations_.

Comment: @John Lawler That is very interesting. From a brief glance at Levin, of which I was previously unaware, I can see that these  verbs may well behave similarly. Thank you for your intervention and expert guidance in this matter.  But does this in any sense belie the comments I have made to Colin Fine, above?

Comment: One searches a location for an object, generally; or searches for an object in/on/at a location. I don't have my copy of Levin handy, but I think that's the "Search" Alternation.

Comment: @John Lawler  That sounds to me as though it endorses exactly what I said.

Comment: WS2 I don't disagree with any of your points. I took it that the OP was asking about whether any other word than _for_ could be used for the target of the search, so I thought your reply was likely to confuse because the other constructions you were using indicated the range of the search.